# why every class file starts with "Êþº¾ "

Tags: java, jvm, .class-file

I don't get it. what is the purpose of "Êþº¾" at the beginning of every class file in java.

I searched but nothing found related.

Comment: Probably because of [`CAFEBABE`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file).

Comment: Why are you opening '.class' files in ascii editor?

Answer (score 3):

Every class file starts with the hex sequence `CAFEBABE`. In the editor/console you're using that byte sequence must render as the characters you're seeing.